# Why is catch() not working with ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

```js
const errorTest = () => {

  const result = $.get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=9790286e305d82fbde77cc1948cf847c&format=1");

  result
    .then(val => console.log(val.rates))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))


}

errorTest()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`.then()` works, but `catch()` doesn't. It keeps showing an error:  `result.then(...).catch is not a function at errorTest.`

Why? `$.get()` is supposed to return a promise, and assign it to `result`. That's why `.then()` works, but why is `catch()` not working?

It works if I use `fetch()` instead.

```
 const result = fetch("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=9790286e305d82fbde77cc1948cf847c&format=1");
```

So, why is `catch()` not working with ajax requests then?

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION**

```js
const errorTest = (a, b) => { 

  const result = $.get("http://dataa.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=9790286e305d82fbde77cc1948cf847c&format=1");

  result
  .then(val => console.log(val.rates))
  //.catch(err => console.error("INSIDE ERROR" + err))

}


try { 
 errorTest()
}
catch(err) { 
  console.log("OUTSIDE ERROR!" + err)
}
```

The link is intentionally incorrect to get an error. If I uncomment the `catch()` inside the function, that inside `catch()` will capture the error. If I comment out, or just remove the inside `catch()`, I would expect the outside `catch()` to get the error, but it's not. Why?

Comment: it;s working fine. i tested with jquery version 3.6.0

Comment: OP added a link to jQuery 3.3.1, but it works just fine with that as well. Tested.

Comment: I added  the jquery

Comment: Rather than just looking at `val.rates` , you might want to check out the full return -> `{
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 105,
    "type": "https_access_restricted",
    "info": "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."
  }
}`

Comment: `result` in your first snippet isn't a promise, it's a [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object. From jQuery 1.5 it has the standard methods you can expect from the Promise API such as `catch`, so maybe check your jQuery version

Comment: Why do I keep getting the error then? I didn't say `then()` doesn't work, I said `catch()` doesn't work.

Comment: Your maybe running a very old version of JQuery.

Comment: Where can I get the new jQuery version? I can't find the link in their website? Can somebody just please paste the link.

Comment: https://jquery.com/   There is a big button that says `Download JQuery`..

Comment: Yep, it works now. I used the latest jQuery, and there's no problem anymore.

Comment: @Keith I don't wanna download. I just wanted a link to the CDN, but I got it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @ihatefacebook  No problem, but that link also shows you CDN's too.  It's just a bit further down, it then takes you to -> https://code.jquery.com/  with all the CDN links..

Comment: @Keith A bit unrelated question but, why when I use `then()` inside the function block, and then use `try .. catch` outside the function, why is the error not thrown at the outside `catch()`, but instead, if there is no `catch()` inside the block, it's just not shown at all?

Comment: @ihatefacebook  Not really sure what your asking, I wonder if it's best to start another question showing example code.

Comment: @Keith I edited my original question to include the my question. Please take a took at it.

Comment: Without using `async / await` a normal try catch is not going to work.  More info -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @Keith So, I'm trying to create a case in which I am using two `catch()`, one inside, and one outside a function in order to demonstrate that the closest one will be used. Is such case even possible?  If I use `async/await` then I can't use `catch()` inside, right?  - because  `await` will just return the resolved promise.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Regarding your problem, i think it just doesn't throw an exception, thats why `.then()` works.

However, instead of using the callback-based promise syntax, i suggest using `async/await`. It's a much cleaner way.

```js
const errorTest = async () => { 

  try {
    const result = await $.get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=ACCESS_TOKEN&format=1");
    console.log(result.rates);
  } catch(e) {
    console.err(e);
  }

 
}

errorTest()
```

Comment: The issue was with the jQuery version. Apparently I wasn't using the latest version. I just tried it with the latest 3.6 version, and it works now.

Comment: A bit unrelated question but, why when I use `then()` inside the function block, and then use `try .. catch` outside the function, why is the error not thrown at the outside `catch()`, but instead, if there is no `catch()` inside the block, it's just not shown at all?